# I don't get video from local cammera using twilio

Tags: javascript, video, twilio

I am building an app for video chat. The backend part in python works fine(making rooms, giving tokens adding right to the room). I can connect to the room and the diod on my notebook shows that the camera is working but it dosen't display video from my local camera. This is my code

```
Twilio.Video.connect(doctor_token, {name: room_name}).then(function (room) {

    Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then(function (track) {
        $("#localVideo").append(track.attach());
    });

    room.on('participantConnected', function (participant) {
        $("#patientVideo").append(participant.track.attach())
    })

});
```

This i part of html

```
  <div>
            <video id="localVideo"></video>
            <video id="patientVideo"></video>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? What is more how to add option to mute voice from my video cammera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Calling `track.attach()` with no arguments will actually create a `<video>` element. Your code is then appending the new `<video>` element to your existing `<video id="localVideo"></video>` element. If you inspect the DOM after this code runs then you will find nested videos.

You have two choices now. You can either turn your existing `<video>` element into a `<div id="localVideo">` and the created video element will be appended to it and you will see your local video. The HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id="localVideo"></div>
  <div id="patientVideo"></div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript stays the same.

Or, you can leave the HTML as it is and pass the ID selector to `track.attach()` which will attach the video from your camera to the existing element.

The JavaScript in this case becomes:

```
Twilio.Video.connect(doctor_token, {name: room_name}).then(function (room) {

  Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then(function (track) {
    track.attach("#localVideo");
  });

  room.on('participantConnected', function (participant) {
    participant.track.attach("#patientVideo");
  });

});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It helped! You are awesome! Could you also tell me how to mute my localvideo?

Comment: You need to get the local audio track and [`disable()`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/LocalAudioTrack.html#disable__anchor) it.